# How to retrieve coordinates of tables using Tabula?

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, data-science, tabula, python-camelot

I am trying to remove tables from a PDF document(converted to image). The idea is to identify the table coordinates and then use it to change the corresponding pixel values to 255(white). I got coordinates using Camelot function using the .bbox option but Camelot identifies non-tables as tables. I felt tabula is better at extracting tables. Can you help me to retrieve table coordinates using Tabula ?

Comment: tabula do not return the location bindings of a cell